# Http Header for "Requester"

Tags: wcf, http, rest, http-headers

I'm writing a WCF service, the purpose of which is to authenticate clients using a shared secret key. Each configured client will have it's own unique shared key, that only the client and the service know of. Part of this process means the auth service needs to be able to look up the configured shared key for each client when they request to be authenticated. The service is using the webHttpBinding, so I'd like to use an HTTP header for this if possible.

Is there a better header for the clients of this service to use than the "Referrer" header to declare their identification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Referer` is probably not a good choice, as I guess the client will know the URI of the server in advance (hardcoded or from a config), and the standard [says](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36):

“The Referer field MUST NOT be sent if the Request-URI was obtained from a source that does not have its own URI”

I think either [`Authorization`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8) with a custom scheme (see also [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617)), or a non-standard header like `X-Client-Id`, would be a reasonable choice.